# How to stop rails new from creating vendor/cache folder?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundle, bundle-install

Earlier I ran these commands:

`bundle install --path vendor/cache`

and

`bundle config set path 'vendor/cache'`

And now,
Whenever I am doing

`rails new app_name`,

a folder `vendor/cache` (with 5K+ files) gets created inside the `app_name` directory.

---

How can I undo the above first two commands so that everything comes back to normal?

I don't want `vendor/cache` to be created every time I do `rails new`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Running this should undo the damage.

```
bundle config unset path
```

See more in the [documentation](https://bundler.io/man/bundle-config.1.html)